# Mod_Mono 2.10 compilation error

Tags: apache, mono, mod-mono

I'm currently trying to install Mono 3.0.3 on OpenSUSE. I've compiled and installed each part (mono 3.0.3, XSP 2.10.1 and Apache HTTPD 2.4.3) from their respective tar balls, but mod_mono 2.10 (and 2.8) both throw compilation errors.

I've made sure all prefixes are the same when compiling and installing each part:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

however make causes mod_mono to output the following:

```
...SNIP...
mod_mono.c: In function ‘send_initial_data’:
mod_mono.c:1981:44: error: ‘conn_rec’ has no member named ‘remote_ip’
mod_mono.c:2029:54: error: ‘conn_rec’ has no member named ‘remote_ip’
mod_mono.c: In function ‘apache_get_groupid’:
mod_mono.c:403:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
mod_mono.c: In function ‘apache_get_userid’:
mod_mono.c:393:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
mod_mono.c: In function ‘apache_get_username’:
mod_mono.c:413:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make[1]: *** [mod_mono_la-mod_mono.lo] Error 1
```

Has anybody seen this before? Is there a solution? Or does mod_mono simply not work with mono 3.0.3 or Apache 2.4.3?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `remote_ip` member in the apache `conn_rec` struct has been renamed recently. The mod_mono you are trying to compile is incompatible with the particular apache version you have. If this is the only error, it should be easy to fix by simply changing the problematic `remote_ip` references to `client_ip` in `mod_mono.c`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and report back

Comment: No, sadly this didn't solve the problem. Additional errors were reported with other functions.